# Openshift3 Does free hosting work

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge, openshift-enterprise

I have created a small Web Application using struts/tiles/mysql/tomcat.
I dont intend to earn any money. Once it is online, it might help parents of my school.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free layer for Openshift Online and you should be able to deploy your application there with very limited resources. 
You can find here more information:
  https://www.openshift.com/pricing/plan-comparison.html

Or you can setup your own server and run Openshift Online in it with

> oc cluster up

https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md